# The Response doesn't Succeed return "0"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2, response

There is a problem when receiving the response,

```
response.body().success
```

it returns **0** but I expect **1**
it shows a toast shows Failed! As the code below which means the response doesn't succeed

```
mService = Common.getFCMService();
private void sendNotificationOrder(String order_number) {
    DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
    Query data = tokens.orderByChild("isServerToken").equalTo(true);
    data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Token serverToken = postSnapShot.getValue(Token.class);
                Notification notification = new Notification("Ziead's Company", "You have New Order" + order_number);
                Sender content = new Sender(serverToken.getToken(), notification);
                mService.sendNotification(content)
                        .enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                                try {
                                       //Here It is Returning "0" not 1                                        System.out.println(response.body().success);
                                        if (response.code() == 200) {
                                            if (response.body().success == 1) {
                                                System.out.println("Succeedd");
                                                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Thank you , Order Place", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                finish();
                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Failed !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.e("ERROR", t.getMessage());

                            }
                        });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Token.java:

```
public class Token {
    private String token;
    private boolean isServerToken;

    public Token() {
    }

    public Token(String token, boolean isServerToken)
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.isServerToken = isServerToken;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public boolean isServerToken() {
        return isServerToken;
    }

    public void setServerToken(boolean serverToken) {
        isServerToken = serverToken;
    }
}
```

Notification.java:

```
public class Notification {
    public String body;
    public String title;

    public Notification(String body, String title) {
        this.body = body;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Sender.java:

```
public class Sender {
    public String to;
    public  Notification notification;

    public Sender(String to, Notification notification) {
        this.to = to;
        this.notification = notification;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public Notification getNotification() {
        return notification;
    }

    public void setNotification(Notification notification) {
        this.notification = notification;
    }
}
```

Common.java:

```
public class Common {
    public static APIService getFCMService(){
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

APIService Interface:

```
public interface APIService {
    @Headers(
            {
                    "Content-Type:application/json",
                    "Authorization:key=AAAA0EXeo9E:APA91bGeAWN69zVVIKh9ib_XA6OkMnEA1S0_sZILrJ1civQVF-eelOAF4o3qCOTZpRgSwb9bySoU92ypchs5BqOE2P1Y_FPlvUanIrV2g7RPCY7IpGjYqSK1rlKVxODm6v8R"
            }
    )
    @POST("fcm/send")
    Call<MyResponse> sendNotification(@Body Sender body);
}
```

RetrofitClient.java:

This is all the code related to the main code

Comment: Hi there, have to try to logcat this `response.body().message` ?

Comment: Hi, I try to print response.body().message but message isn't defined didn't recognize message

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine

Comment: Can you contact me to my emaill ?

Comment: for sure send me your email

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine

Comment: ticherhaz@gmail.com